# Problem while trying to setup a connection between two base stations in NS-2

Tags: ns2

I am new to NS-2 and am trying to create an environment whereby a mobile node(UE) would act as a dummy base station for its nearby mobile nodes. Hence any data requested from them would be routed from the UE and then to the requesting node. But i am facing problems while creating the following topology. My procedure being:
1. Create a single domain and 2 clusters in it.
2. Declare the main base station and serving node in it.
3. The second cluster being defined with the serving node as a base station. 
4. This serving node is connected to many other nodes in the second cluster.